# Stash set_list and cartthrob order_items not playing nicely, parse order perhaps?

Tags: cartthrob, stash, parse-order

I've got the following code which is meant to output a list of authors of orders in cartthrob that match a certain entry id:

```
{exp:stash:set_list name="participants" scope="user" save="yes" parse_tags="yes"}

         {exp:channel:entries channel="orders" dynamic="no" status="Paid"}

                    {exp:cartthrob:order_items order_id="{entry_id}"}
                           {stash:authors_id}{item:author_id}{/stash:authors_id}
                     {/exp:cartthrob:order_items}

           {/exp:channel:entries}

   {/exp:stash:set_list}
```

But it doesn't pick up the author_id from the cartthrob tag at all. If i take out that cartthrob tag and just get stash to pick up the author_id from the channel tag it works fine.
I've tried every combination of parse="inward" you can imagine but nothing gives.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default `parse_depth` is 1. In this case you need to parse two layers deep (because you have two nested tag pairs), so set `parse_depth="2"`.

Comment: I had no idea that param existed. Thanks a million million!!!
Mark, will you marry me?